# Binding Lists With Different Numbers of Columns

Tags: r, list

I have a list ("example_list") that looks something like this:

```
[[344]]
  col1 col2 col3
1             \t\t

[[345]]
  col1                   col2                      col3                    col4                  col5          col6                       col7
1                                                    \t\t                    <NA>                  <NA>          <NA>                       <NA>
2      a1 b1 x1 Phone: d1 g1
3                qhdbqw           kj8,    h1   g6          <NA>                       <NA>

[[346]]
  col1 col2 col3
1             \t\t

> summary(example_list)
       Length Class      Mode
  [1,]  0     -none-     NULL
  [2,]  3     data.frame list
  [3,]  3     data.frame list
  [4,] 12     data.frame list
  [5,]  3     data.frame list
  [6,]  8     data.frame list
  [7,]  3     data.frame list
  [8,]  6     data.frame list
  [9,]  3     data.frame list
```

I want to convert this list into a data frame. Normally I would have used the following command to do this:

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, example_list)
```

But since I have a different number of columns, I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I looked online and thought of the following way to try and solve this problem:

```
library(dplyr)
results_dataframe <- do.call(bind_rows, example_list)
```

This seems to have worked - but I would be interested in hearing opinions about the approach I have used.

- Have I done this correctly - are there better ways to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `bind_rows` can be directly applie dto a list i.e. `bind_rows(example_list)` is enough

Answer (score 1):

dplyr's `bind_rows` will silently fill extra columns with na, so this should be sufficient on its own.

```
df1 = tribble(
  ~x1, ~x2, ~x3,
  "a", "b", "c",
  "x", "y", "z"
)

df2 = tribble(
  ~x1, ~x2, ~x3, ~x4,
  "z", "y", "x", "d",
  "b", "c", "a", "d"
)

l = list(df1, df2)

bind_rows(l)
```